# Immutable backups in the cloud for individuals (not companies)

Tags: backup

I am looking for a backup solution for my Google Drive, Google Keep, and Android Contacts, that will allow me to create a backup in the cloud that cannot be deleted, even when someone accesses my account with my credentials on my behalf.

The data can be downloaded.

Perhaps it is possible to set a time period after which a backup can be deleted, or its permanence updated and renewed.

Only in this way can my data be secure from being deleted by someone accessing my account.

Perhaps I am ill or old or cannot move and need to entrust my account to someone else to carry out basic tasks on my behalf.

However, this way my data is not safe.

However, most solutions out there seem to only cater to businesses, and not individuals.

Is there any solution out there that caters to individuals?

Comment: See https://www.franzoni.eu/ransomware-resistant-backups/ for an interesting blog post on how make 'ransomware resistant' (i.e. immutable) backups using AWS S3 buckets.

Comment: https://www.idrive.com/s3-storage-e2/ransomware

Answer (score 0):

One possible option is to try S3 Object Lock. This help you defining specific period for immutable records or (depend of mode) only specific users (with appropriate privileges can modify the files. For more information you will find the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lock.html#object-lock-best-practices).